# How do I make the priority menu disappear

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I recently upgraded to Lollipop on my Nexus 5.

To put the phone on silent, I press the volume-up button and select Priority. Great.

Now how do I make that menu go away? I can click on an empty area of my homescreen, but that seems like a bad solution. What is there wasn't an open place to click on? Isn't there a sane way to exit that dialog?

Comment: The back button doesn't do it?

Comment: You'd think it would. But it doesn't.

Comment: Just only an observation: When you select "All", priority menu will disappear in 4 seconds without doing anything. However, for "Priority" and "None", you have to wait for 10 seconds. I assume this is not the "solution" you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to tap an empty space on the screen; if the screen is full of touch-sensitive stuff (homescreen) you can open Recents/Overview and swipe there, then close it again. Not ideal, but the best you can do.